# sqlite3 change in the func callback the parameter void* notUsed to int* C++

Tags: c++, sqlite

I need to return a integer from callback, but I not succeeded.
I tried - but nothing.
I will be very glad if you will help me.

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    sqlite3* db;
    char* zErrMsg;
    sqlite3_open("try.db", &db);

    //do something...

    string query = "select * from myTable";
    int *ptr;
    sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), callback, ptr, &zErrMsg);

    cout << ptr << endl;

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}



int callback(void* notUsed, int argc, char** argv, char** azCol)
{
    /*
    chane void* notUsed to int*
    ???how???
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You really should use a [cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlite/5456/sqlite3-stmt-prepared-statement-c-api/19406/reading-data-from-a-cursor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an address of valid memory (e.g. on stack) or allocate it (heap) to the callback function, if you allocate you have to free it also.

The forth argument of the `sqlite3_exec()` function will be the first argument of the `callback()` function wich is of type `void*`. So if you pass the address of an `int` you have to interpret the `void*` as an `int*`.

I changed it so the memory (`int someNumber`) is in the callers function (main) and pass the address of it. In the callback function you need to cast the `void*` to the pointer type you expect, here `int*` and assign a value.

It should be:

```
...
int main()
{
    ...
    int someNumber;
    sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(), callback, &someNumber, &zErrMsg);

    cout << someNumber << endl;
    ...
}

int callback(void* someNumberArg, int argc, char** argv, char** azCol)
{
    int* someNumber = reinterpret_cast<int*> (someNumberArg);
    *someNumber = 42;
    return 0;
}
```